# Relate Database Names With Metadata from SQL Server System Catalogue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to produce a report that shows metadata about the tables and columns across databases on a server.

Ideally I would like to have the databases themselves included as a column in the report but cannot find a suitable relationship between the various `sys` objects on `SQL Server`.

So far I have:

> DECLARE @R VARCHAR(50)
>
> SET @R = 'Test1'
>
> DECLARE @T VARCHAR(50)
>
> SET @T = 'TESTSTUFF'
>
> SELECT  AC.[name] AS [COLUMN_NAME], T.[name] AS [TABLE_NAME], @R AS [DATABASE], '' AS [DESCRIPTION]
>
> FROM Test1.sys.[tables] AS T
>
> INNER JOIN Test1.sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]   `
>
> WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT   AC.[name] AS [column_name], 
>           T.[name] AS [table_name], @T AS [DATABASE], '' AS [DESCRIPTION]
>
> FROM TESTSTUFF.sys.[tables] AS T
>
> INNER JOIN TESTSTUFF.sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]
>
> WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0

By making parameters of the database name, I'm introducing a high degree of maintainability that I feel is unnecessary. Ideally I'd want this as a view because it will update itself automatically each time database objects are added.

The goal is to achieve something like this:

> DECLARE @D VARCHAR(50)
>
> SET @D = (SELECT NAME FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb') )
>
> SELECT  AC.[name] AS [COLUMN_NAME], T.[name] AS [TABLE_NAME], @D AS [DATABASE], '' AS [DESCRIPTION]
>
> FROM sys.[tables] AS T
>     INNER JOIN sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]
>
> INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON `?????`
>
> WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This `SET @D = (SELECT NAME FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb') )` will return more than 1 row, so you will most likely get an error when this is run. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I'm pretty sure the script wouldn't error.  `@D` would be populated with whichever `NAME` SQL Server decided to return first that time.

Comment: I just tried it on my server and got this error. `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: `Select Top 1 Name` would resolve that error.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of this syntax, which also does not error:   `SELECT @D = NAME FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't use a view, you could use a script or stored procedure that generates a dynamic SQL statement. The example below generates a UNION ALL query of the catalog views of each database, each qualified with the database name.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = STUFF(
    (SELECT 'UNION ALL
    SELECT AC.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC AS [COLUMN_NAME], T.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS_SC AS [TABLE_NAME], N''' + name + N''' AS [Database], '''' AS [DESCRIPTION]
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.[tables] AS T 
    INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.[all_columns] AC ON T.[object_id] = AC.[object_id]
    WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0 '
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)'),1,11,'') + N';';

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, this gives exactly whats needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]` instead of the `sys` view, it exposes the `[TABLE_CATALOG]` column which can be used to join to `sys.databases`.

Comment: This only gives me the metadata for the database I'm currently using. If I use this in the `join` I will only get results for one database while excluding the others, or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

1. sp_MSforeachdb stored procedure to go around all DB on your server
2. The link between DB-Table-Schema can be made with this t-sql script

   ```
   SELECT DB_NAME () as DataBaseName,
   s.Name as SchemaName,
   t.NAME as TableName
   FROM  sys.tables t
   JOIN  sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
   JOIN  sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
   JOIN  sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
   JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
   WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 and t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
   GROUP BY  t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows,t.create_date 
   ORDER BY  DB_NAME(),s.Name,t.Name
   ```